# Why can't a pointer's value be accessed with square bracket syntax when returned from a function?

Tags: c

I am learning basic C, and I am still trying to understand arrays and pointers. I am trying to write a `push` function to mimic the behavior of an array in Javascript, but with a workaround, since arrays cannot be returned in C.

When I access the returned pointer with `(*p+3)`, it yields the correct value, but `p[3]` does not. However, I can still access the correct value within `push()` with `p[3]`. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void br() {
    putchar('\n');
}

int *push(int *arr, size_t size, int val) { 
    int *arr2 = calloc(size + 1, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
    }
    arr2[size] = val;
    return arr2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int myNums[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    int *p = push(myNums, sizeof(myNums), 4);
    printf("%i", (*p + 3));
    br();
    printf("%i", p[3]);
    br();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I think there is a better solution using structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct{
    int*values;
    int length;
} intArray;

void printInts(intArray * arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr->length; i++){
        printf("Value %i: %i\n",i,arr->values[i]);
    }
}

intArray push(intArray * arr, int value){
    arr->length++;
    arr->values = realloc(arr->values, sizeof(int)*arr->length);
    arr->values[arr->length-1] = value;
    return *arr;
}

intArray pop(intArray * arr){
    arr->length--;
    arr->values = realloc(arr->values, sizeof(int)*arr->length);
    return *arr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    intArray myNums;
    myNums = push(&myNums,15);
    myNums = push(&myNums,30);
    myNums = push(&myNums,45);
    myNums = push(&myNums,60);
    myNums = pop(&myNums);

    printInts(&myNums);

    /* expected output:
    Value 0: 15
    Value 1: 30
    Value 2: 45
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p[3]` is equivalent to `*(p+3)` and not `(*p+3)` (=`*p+3`). It just _seems_ to work because you used 1,2,3,4 as values so the first value (1) plus 3 happens to be equal to the last value (4)... Try something like 10,20,30,40 instead to see what I mean.

Comment: Also, note that your function leaks memory every time it's used. You should instead establish semantics that say any array passed in must be dynamically allocated too (not be a local variable like it's now), then the function can free the old memory after copying the data. Additionally you are confusing the size of the array in bytes with the size of the array in elements.

Comment: Please confirm you expect `4  4` as output.

Comment: Whoops, yes I see that now - 4 was only returned because of how the original array was set up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two mistakes in the code:

- `int *p = push(myNums, sizeof(myNums), 4);`

  `sizeof(myNums)` is not the length of the array (ie: the number of elements), but its size in bytes.

  You can use `sizeof(myNums) / sizeof(myNums[0])` to compute the number of elements at compile time.
- `printf("%i", (*p + 3));`

  You first print `*p + 3`, which is not the same as `*(p + 3)`: you get the expected output only by coincidence because `*p`, which is equivalent to `p[0]` happens to have the value `1`. Conversely, `p[3]` accesses the fourth element of the reallocated array, whose value is undefined as it was copied from data beyond the end of the original array passed to `push()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *push(int *arr, size_t count, int val) { 
    int *arr2 = calloc(count + 1, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
    }
    arr2[count] = val;
    return arr2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int myNums[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int *p = push(myNums, sizeof(myNums) / sizeof(myNums[0]), 4);
    printf("%i\n", *(p + 3));
    printf("%i\n", p[3]);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had some problems in there...